# useEffect is getting called multiple times (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing some issues while building an Infinite scroll using ReactJs and Intersection observer API.

On Loading the application for the first time, the API is being called twice instead of once. I think this is happening because of strict mode but not 100% sure. And when I make some changes within the `InfiniteScroll` component (such as changing the text from "Loading" to "Loading..."), the useEffect hook of the `usePosts` hook is triggered again. As a result, the API is called once more with `page=1`, causing the `setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...posts]);` setter function to add duplicate data to the data array. Ideally, the hook should only execute when the component is initially mounted and when there are changes to the `pageNum` dependency of the useEffect.

Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-satoshi-rnrhsr?file=/src/InfiniteScroll.js

InfiniteScroll:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import usePosts from "./usePosts";

const InfiniteScroll = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const lastPostRef = useRef();
  const { data, loading, isLastPage } = usePosts(page); // Todo: add error

  const content = data.map((post, i) => {
    if (data.length === i + 1) {
      return (
        <p key={post.id} ref={lastPostRef}>
          {post.title}
        </p>
      );
    }
    return <p key={post.id}>{post.title}</p>;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {content}
      {loading && <p className="center">Loading More Posts...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScroll;
```

usePosts.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getPosts } from "./api";

const usePosts = (pageNum) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isLastPage, setIsLastPage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const { posts, total, skip, limit } = await getPosts(pageNum, 10);
      setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...posts]);
      setLoading(false);
      if (total === skip * limit) setIsLastPage(true);
    };

    getData();
  }, [pageNum]);

  return { data, loading, isLastPage };
};

export default usePosts;
```

Comment: your getData function should be wrapped into useCallback and the dependency of useCallback function should be pageNum. and then you call that function into useEffect.

Comment: Your'e adding a state variable into dependency array. That's why when the state variable changes it re-renders the component, when it re-render the compoent means changing the state variable means re-rendering the component, and so on...

Comment: Remove React.StrictMode from your main.js or index.js at the root

Comment: @CraZyDroiD removing StrictMode won't solve the problem of duplicate content.

Comment: @PremalKatigar Adding useCallback didn't solve the problem. I added a codesandbox link in the question for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what it fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-3zbqlt?file=/src/InfiniteScroll.js

1. Just remove `React.StrictMode` in the `App.js`: React StrictMode renders components twice on dev server
2. You should use `useMemo` for `content` to memorize the data map
3. You should use `index` as `key` because your `post.id` is not unique

Hope It can help

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think this solves the problem. Try changing text from `Loading..` to `Loading` it'll add duplicate data to the data array and that's why it's showing the duplicate key warning.

Comment: Oh I see. I believe that only happened when there was a dev environment problem.
(react's state retention mechanism). If you really want to prevent it. You should check duplicate items. But it will affect your performance. But I think you shouldn't. When you change something, you can reload the page

Comment: I think, I can use new Set to prevent storing duplicating content in the state variable.

Comment: You can't. Because the result of API is always a new array of new objects. You have to loop `data` and check by `id`

Comment: I just updated the code for your purpose. Hope it can help. But as above I said. You shouldn't do that for your best performance